# API not returning the correct JSON (react/express/axios)

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I feel like this should be a duplicate...If it is I'm not finding the correct thread.

I have an `Express API` (using `mongoose`) on a server with `React` front end. The API should return a `JSON` to the client.

Problem: It works fine with `Postman` but returns the wrong `JSON` in `React`

What I'm sending in `Postman` (this generates a correct response):

```
{"fileHashValue"
:
"e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"}
```

Server Code:

```
app.get("/userData", function(req, res) {
  const fileHashValue = req.body.fileHashValue;
  UserData = UserData.findOne(
    {
      fileHashValue
    },
    function(err, userdata) {
      res.json({
        userdata
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Client Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get(
      "http://ec2-52-53-190-3.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/userData",
      {
        fileHashValue:
          "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
}
```

It seems like this should all work, but its responding as if I had sent a blank request. IE, if I send a blank request in `Postman` it gives me the same result that I'm logging in `React`. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `axios.get()` is expecting a request config as the second parameter (not your raw params).

You can set your params as follows:

```
axios.get("http://ec2-52-53-190-3.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/userData", {
    params: {
        fileHashValue: "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
    }
})
.then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
});
```

A more detailed explanation : https://flaviocopes.com/axios/#get-requests

---

As the other answer mentioned, using the `get` verb may not fit your needs. Get is mostly used to fetch a ressource and is not able to contain a body. Using `post` can prevent this. Post is mostly used to create a ressource and can have a body :

```
axios.post("http://ec2-52-53-190-3.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/userData", {
    params: {
        fileHashValue: "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
    }
})
.then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
});
```

If your objective really is to simply get an element, I suggest changing your routes architecture to include the id that you are attempting to get in the url :

```
axios.get("http://ec2-52-53-190-3.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/userData/e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855", {})
.then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
});
```

And adapt your backend :

```
app.get("/userData/:id", function(req, res)
```

The id will then be accessible in `req.params.id`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this is displaying the same log as in the original question.

Comment: Weird, can you print out what's in your `req.body` variable on the back-end ?

Comment: Also, what is printed in the network part of your browser's console after sending the request ?

Comment: `postman` returns e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

`react` returns "undefined"

Thanks for your help, I need to leave for something else for a few hours, have a great day :)

Comment: this is when I add a `console.log(req.body.fileHashValue)` into my server code

Comment: Alright, got it, can you show me what your browser network console looks like after sending your request

Comment: The browser console logs `create_date: "2018-12-16T11:34:42.703Z"
myID: "b2092b3e6f270099fe4433a67e9f32dedf19fb6a1de2a0229da2"
__v: 0
_id: "5c16385222e88522785c9758"` This is an entry in the database. It is the same entry that you get if you send an empty request with postman.

Comment: Alright, I updated my post, tell me if you still have troubles

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) This will hopefully be a good thread as it now contains two ways to address this issue. Like I said, none of the tutorials that I was following (several) went into these nuances, so I'm sure other newbs might run into similar issues.

Comment: You'rewelcome, glad it could help someone. Well you know, I've never used axios myself, we're all newbies here

Answer (score 1):

As per the instructions in this thread, it is not recommended to .get (really at all). As a rookie, I never recall any of the tutorials mentioning this.

[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

The answer to the question is to switch the client and server logic both to `axios.post` and send the `json` as shown in the original post.